# Property Getter / Setter not part of an interface contract

Tags: c#, properties, immutability

Why getters / setters are not part of interface contract ? By example:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int Id { get; } 
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Why is it allowed to have setter here even though interface declaration is different ? 
The problem I am having here is with immutability. Clients implementing my interface will be allowed to create mutable types which I want to discourage. Am I forced to fall back to using methods and readonly fields ?

Comment: yes, interface is not meant to hold variables of mutable properties. overriding is meant to implement new implementations and not keep the originals as they are.

Comment: I just discovered this, too, while attempting to write an IIdentifiable<T> interface. The setter can still be present in an inheriting class, which is not intended; I wanted the interface to be immutable. This kind of sucks.

Answer (score 3):

To implement an Interface you must provide *at least* the methods it contains.
You are allowed to supply more, (for example to implement *another* interface).

You can think of the getter/setter pair as methods `set_Id(int i)` and `get_Id()`.
In fact, that is how they are modeled on the lower levels of the CLI.

So `set_Id(int i)` is just an additional method provided by the implementer and there is nothing
you can do to prevent him from doing so.

Answer (score 3):

Interfaces provides contract. It says that whoever implementing me(the interface) should at least implement all the specifications provided by them.

It doesn't restrict anything, You can implement whatever extra members you wish to provide other than the interface contract specifies, but no less.

Also, c# as a language provides no support for immutability so you have no ways to prevent user from implementing the mutable type.

> Am I forced to fall back to using methods and readonly fields ?

I'm not sure what is your question here, because you said *Clients implementing my interface will be allowed to create mutable types*. Who is the client? Another programmer?

Anyways, `readonly` is not **really readonly**. Remember you can always modify them with the reflection gun, it is more powerful than `readonly`.

Comment: True, however you can still `public int Id { get; private set; }` to make sure `Id` isn't settable from the outside.

Comment: You can't create private members on interfaces

Comment: @MotiAzu I guess you mean in the type you're implementing the interface you can do `public int Id { get; private set; }`. If so, yes you can do, but that's not same as immutable.

Comment: As already said somewhere in SO: altering readonly fields through reflection is not documented behavior and therefore not future-proof code and might change in future implementations of the language. Certainly, **readonly** is currently not 100%-proof way to assure immutability, however the best one we can get.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Of course, but when the only way to violate it is reflection, it's good enough for me.